# Get current logged user name for user "Account operates as System"

Tags: user-profile, user-accounts, user, login

When I'm try to get current logged user name for account domain\username and I added many users to this option "Account operates as System" In code I got the system account not the real name of user "Domain\username" and i want the real name and real Id for this used to difference between users all of them are with option "Account operates as System"
The code I used :

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this if I understand you correct?

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

and

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID;
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: its give me the name ok but how to get the id of this user

Comment: iv just changed the post, lol forgot to add the ID part ;)

Comment: SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID or .Name not works for me that what I was use

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name get the name as I want thanks